# Monitor for dropped WiFi connection

Tags: wireless

How can I tell when the pi losses WiFi connection?  Is there a program to do this?  Then auto reconnect?

Alternatively, is there a setting which turns off the WiFi if it is not used - and how can this be disabled.

Answer (score 5):

Was having the same problem. Couple of good solutions on the Raspberry Pi forums, I like the script Dweeby posted at the end of the thread.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=16054

Comment: Hello alex. In order to prevent link rot would you please summarize the contents of the link? Thank you!